# Tableview - wait for cell to be removed before adding a new one

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

I have a table view, in which if you select a row, it add a picker below the row. But if another row is selected, it hides the first picker (removed the row with the picker) and then adds a new picker.

Now my question is, how to I wait for the remove animation to finish before adding a new row?

This is how I add a new row. It's in the didSelectRow method.

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
pickerInsertedAtIndexPath = selectedIndex;
NSArray *indexes = @[selectedIndex];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

This is how I remove a row. This is in the willSelectRow method.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no callbacks as to when the table view animations end. You'll have to wait for an interval of your choice before adding the new picker.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matches your scenario but can you use:

[`tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW35)

A `UITableViewDelegate` callback that will inform you when a cell has been removed from the `UITableView`?